# Eigenvalues and Timestep restriction Follow up

Tags: numerical-analysis, eigenvalues, time-integration, runge-kutta

This is a follow-up question to the previous questions I had on eigenvalues. Please let me know if I should edit the previous question itself for asking this.

If the eigenvalues of a matrix generated from a lower order coarse mesh discretization are negative, can we comment anything on the eigenvalues of the matrix that we get by refining the mesh or using a higher order polynomial for discretization of the same pde?